# Using CSS background: url() in Windows 8 Metro Apps

Tags: javascript, css, windows, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am creating some DOM elements in Javascript and add some classes to them which I then use the classes in my CSS to add a background image using:

```
background: url('/images/reply.png');
```

However when I do this and run the app the images show, but so does a thin border and a small black dot in the center. This box and dot show up also when you use a bad URL in the CSS background: url() part. But once the URL is correct, it still shows up along with the image.

Anyone figure out why this happens in Win 8?

Comment: the thin border and black dot aren't something I'm seeing with an invalid URL in the background, can you provide a bit more context - perhaps upload an image? can you reproduce with static HTML/SS.

Comment: +1 on the screen shot; without that I'm baffled by what you're seeing.

Comment: for some reason if works if I initially set the image to have a src attribute and then later give it a css background:url() on hover. But if I initially use CSS then the problem persists. I will try to add a pic

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ms-appx://" prefix:

```
.myClass {
   background: url("ms-appx:///images/myImage.png");
}
```